# Method body not executing?

Tags: python, methods

I'm running this python code and having a problem with the accel function. The rotate method works fine when left and right are pressed however when up is pressed nothing happens. I've stepped through the code in a debugger and the my_ship.accel line is executed but it doesn't go to method body, it just continues as if that line isn't there. Idk what's wrong please help. Also my_ship is the name of a Ship object and it is defined properly lower in my code.

```
import simplegui
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

class ImageInfo:
    def __init__(self, center, size, radius = 0, lifespan = None, animated = False):
        self.center = center
        self.size = size
        self.radius = radius
        if lifespan:
            self.lifespan = lifespan
        else:
            self.lifespan = float('inf')
        self.animated = animated

    def get_center(self):
        return self.center

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def get_lifespan(self):
        return self.lifespan

    def get_animated(self):
        return self.animated

    def change_center(self, new_center):
        self.center = new_center

# ship image
ship_info = ImageInfo([45, 45], [90, 90], 35)
ship_image = simplegui.load_image("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/double_ship.png")

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, angle, image, info):
        self.pos = [pos[0],pos[1]]
        self.vel = [vel[0],vel[1]]
        self.thrust = False
        self.angle = angle
        self.angle_vel = 0
        self.image = image
        self.image_center = info.get_center()
        self.image_size = info.get_size()
        self.radius = info.get_radius()
        self.info = info
        self.accel = 10
        self.angle_accel = .1

    def draw(self,canvas):
        if not self.thrust:
            self.info.change_center(ship_center)
            canvas.draw_image(self.image, self.image_center, self.image_size, self.pos,     self.image_size, self.angle)
        else:
            self.info.change_center(thrust_ship_center)
            canvas.draw_image(self.image, self.image_center, self.image_size, self.pos, self.image_size, self.angle)

    def update(self):
        self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
        self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]
        self.angle += self.angle_vel

    def accel(self):
        self.thrust = True
        self.vel[0] += self.accel
        self.vel[1] += self.accel

    def rotate(self, direction):
        if direction == "left":
            self.angle_vel -= self.angle_accel
        elif direction == "right":
            self.angle_vel += self.angle_accel
        else:
            print "error"

def keydown_handler(key):
    if key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['left']:
        my_ship.rotate("left")
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['right']:
        my_ship.rotate("right")
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['up']:
        my_ship.accel            
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['space']:
        self.angle_vel += self.angle_accel
def keyup_handler(key):
    if key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['left']:
        my_ship.rotate("right")
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['right']:
        my_ship.rotate("left")


my_ship = Ship([WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2], [0, 0], 1, ship_image, ship_info)
```

Comment: In the future, please strip your code down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And "verifiable" means that you have to get the indentation right—if we can't run your program because it just raises an `IndentationError`, or fails to call a method because it was defined locally to another method instead of on the class, we can't debug your program. So, you'll only get an answer if the problem happens to be simple enough to guess.

Comment: Just added indentations. Takes like 10 minutes to hit 4 spaces in front of every line there must be a better way....

Comment: Select the code, and click the `{}` button, and it will add 4 spaces to every line (assuming at least one of the lines was flush with the left column). But your edited version clearly still isn't right. For example, you've got `def accel` indented farther than the other methods, and the same as the code it controls, which would raise an `IndentationError`. And at least one `else` body that's at the wrong indentation too.

Comment: It's not like that in my actual code. There it's fixed now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
my_ship.accel
```

Doesn't call the method `my_ship.accel`, any more than `2` calls the number `2`. To call something in Python, you need parentheses. So:

```
my_ship.accel()
```

(If you're wondering why Python does it this way when other languages, like Ruby, don't… well, this means that you can use the method object `my_ship.accel` as a value—store it to call later, pass it to `map`, etc.)

---

But you've got another problem on top of that.

You define a method `accel` on `Ship` objects. But you also assign an integer value `10` to `self.accel` on `Ship` objects. There's no way `self.accel` can mean two different things at once, both the method and the number. So, which one "wins"? In this case, the `self.accel = 10` happens at the time you constructed your `Ship`, which is later, so it wins.

So, when you write `my_ship.accel`, you're just referring to the number `10`. And when you write `my_ship.accel()`, you're trying to *call* the number `10` as if it were a function. Hence the `TypeError`.

The solution is to not reuse the same name for two different things. Often, naming functions after verbs and attributes after nouns is a good way to avoid this problem—although you also have to avoid gratuitous abbreviations, because otherwise you're probably going to abbreviate `acceleration` and `accelerate` to the same `accel`, as you did here.

Comment: I got an error with the parentheses. TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: THANK YOU <3 that was dumb of me to use the same name haha thanks so much it works now!